# Converting file size from MB to bytes and comparing it using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I given a try to convert variable value of 23.45 MB to bytes using below way but comparison fails. I'm converting values by appending 0s and removing MB and space.

OS: Linux
Language: Bash

> fileSize=23.45 MB (file size in MB)
>
> existingFileSize=23457676 (file size in bytes)

```
content=$(curl -L ${url})
fileSize=`echo "${content}" | grep -o -P '(?<=fileSize">).*(?='${myFile}')' | head -c8`

fileSize=`echo ${fileSize}0000 | sed -e 's/./''/g'  | sed -e 's/MB /''/g'`

if [ "${fileSize}" != "${existingFileSize}" ]; then
   echo -e "\tFile size is different than local file size\n"
else
   echo -e "\tFile size is same as local file size\n"
fi
echo ${fileSize}
echo ${existingFileSize}
```

So what is best way to convert file size MB to byte and then compare with existing file size? I did googling but it has most of the answers from byte to MB. How can I do this using Bash?

Comment: Where are you originally setting `fileSize`?

Comment: Getting it from URL, let me mention it. Thanks Jonny!

Comment: then your problem is going to be rounding issues, you cannot compare them exactly since the MB version is a rounded value.. If you want you can get the rounded value locally and hope they match

Comment: Use md5sum if you want to compare two files or their contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `$fileSize` becomes `23450000`, which is not equal to `23457676`. If you only care about the integer number of megabytes for the comparison, you could use:

```
croppedFileSize=${fileSize%.*}
existingMB=$(($existingFileSize/1000000))

if [ $croppedFileSize -ne $existingMB ]; then
    echo -e "\tFile size is different than local file size\n"
else
    echo -e "\tFile size is same as local file size\n"
fi
```

In your example, both `croppedFileSize` and `existingMB` are `23`, so it prints the `File size is same as local file size` message. Bash doesn't handle floating point numbers, so using integers makes things easy.

Comment: Thanks but it is not exact file comparison using just first two digits.

Comment: @JiteshSojitra : Your Q asks "... what is best way to convert file size MB to byte and then compare with existing file size". This response answers that Q to the extent that is possible. You need to update your Q to indicate that you want "file comparison using just first two digits"  (and preferably post the correct Q the first time so people don't waste their time). Good luck to all.